# Logical error in javascript changing classNames

Tags: javascript

This script contains logical error, where?
It does only calculate avg. for first number, not second and so on...

```
window.onload = function() {
    var amountOfNumbers = 0;
    var total = 0;
    document.getElementById("uitkomst").innerHTML = "Er zijn nog geen cijfers ingevoerd";
    document.getElementById("cijfer").onblur = function() { 
        total = parseFloat(this.value);
        amountOfNumbers++;
        this.value = "";        
        document.getElementById("uitkomst").innerHTML = "Het gemiddelde van deze "+amountOfNumbers+" cijfers is "+(total/amountOfNumbers);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to increment `total` rather than reset it.

```
total += parseFloat(this.value);
//    ^--- Add to the total
```

Without the `+` there, `total` will be equal to the current value, not the sum of all of the numbers.